# POST Request coming up blank, why?

Tags: php, email, post, request

I have the following code saved as send.php:

```php
<?php
$to_email = "person@gmail.com";
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$body = "Hi, This is test email send by PHP Script";
$headers = "From: Me@myWebsite.com";

if ( mail($to_email, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    echo("Email successfully sent to $to_email...");
} else {
    echo("Email sending failed...");
}
?>
```

The email sends if I navigate to `https://myWebsite.com/Stuff/send.php`
and make `$subject = "something"`

But if I set `$subject` to be a POST variable. It does not send the subject when I write this URL in the browser (as in, the email still sends but the subject is now blank):

```
 https://myWebsite.com/Stuff/send.php?subject=notworking
```

Comment: `$_GET['subject']` fetches the subject from the URL, `$_POST['subject']` fetches it from POST (i.e. submitting the form with a POST method).

Comment: But say there is a web form on the internet. It is using a post request. And you want to play with it in the address bar... so you can't do this?

Comment: If you want to fetch the subject from the URL with `?subject=asd`, then you *need* `$_GET['subject']`. You can't use `POST` unless you send the data over POST.. There's also `$_REQUEST` that can get data from either POST or GET, but I would recommend you choose either POST or GET, and not REQUEST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get both `$_POST`  and `$_GET` you can use `$_REQUEST` which will work for both.

In your code replace

```
$subject = $_GET['subject'];
```

With

```
$subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
```

If someone direct hit the URL in browser without paramter subject you can prevent them using

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST['subject']))
{
  $to_email = "person@gmail.com";
  $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'];
  $body = "Hi, This is test email send by PHP Script";
  $headers = "From: Me@myWebsite.com";

  if ( mail($to_email, $subject, $body, $headers))
    echo("Email successfully sent to $to_email...");
  else
    echo("Email sending failed...");
}
```

Comment: Awesome it works! But question, say there is a web form on the internet. It is using POST requests. And you want to play with it in the url bar on your browser, you cannot do this then?

Comment: `isset($_REQUEST['subject']) && !empty($_REQUEST['subject'])` is redundant. `!empty($_REQUEST['subject'])` is enough.

Comment: @Qirel thank you for spotting that, I have updated accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the values from the URL parameters then you need to use the `$_GET`
global variable to get the data like this,

```
<?php
$to_email = "person@gmail.com";
$subject = $_GET['subject'];
$body = "Hi, This is test email send by PHP Script";
$headers = "From: Me@myWebsite.com";

if ( mail($to_email, $subject, $body, $headers)) {
    echo("Email successfully sent to $to_email...");
} else {
    echo("Email sending failed...");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it.

```
 <?php
    $to_email = "person@gmail.com";
    $subject = (isset($_GET['subject']) && (!empty($_GET['subject']))?$_GET['subject']:"No Subject";
    $body = "Hi, This is test email send by PHP Script";
    $headers = "From: Me@myWebsite.com";

    if ( mail($to_email, $subject, $body, $headers))
        echo("Email successfully sent to $to_email...");
    else
        echo("Email sending failed...");
?>
```

Comment: You don't need to check for `isset()` and `!empty()`. Simply checking for `!empty()` alone is enough.